# Given a triangle, find the intersection of an angle bisector and the opposite side, knowing that the bisector segment has a fixed angle and length.

Tags: geometry

Given the following image:

[image: Image explaining the problem]

With the following knowledge:

- Angle $\alpha^*$ is known (fixed*)
- Length $h^*$ is known (fixed*)
- Length $w$ is known (variable)
- Line segment $XA$ is angle bisector for $\angle OXB$

**Calculate the length $z$.**

$z$ will change as $w$ changes. Angle $\beta$ will also change, but angle $\alpha^{*}$ and length $h^*$ are always the same. Since $h^*$ and $\alpha^*$ are fixed and known, the line segment $XA$ is also fixed and known - it just moves when $B$ moves.

I think there is only one solution but I can't find it, after a few hours of trying to solve this. Does anyone see what I don't?

Comment: It is not clear what the difference is between `fixed` and `variable`. The respective elements are either known or unknown.

Comment: Yeah I guess that's true. This is for a programming project so I view it in terms of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

- draw the altitude from $X$ to $OB$ then: $\;\;h = AX \,\sin(\alpha)$
- by the [law of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) in $\triangle XOA\,$: $\;\;\cfrac{z}{\sin(\beta)} = \cfrac{AX}{\sin(\alpha+\beta)}$

The above gives $z$ in terms of $\,h,\alpha,\beta\,$: $$\,z = \cfrac{h\,\sin(\beta)}{\sin(\alpha)\,\sin(\alpha+\beta)}\,$$

$\,z'=AB\,$ can be calculated in symmetric fashion (replacing $\alpha \mapsto \pi - \alpha$): $$\;z' = \cfrac{h\,\sin(\beta)}{\sin(\alpha)\,\sin(\alpha-\beta)}\,$$

Substituting the above in the equality $\,z+z'=w\,$ gives an equation that can be solved for $\,\beta\,$:

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
\frac{h}{\sin(\alpha)}\left(\frac{\sin(\beta)}{\sin{(\alpha+\beta)}}+\frac{\sin(\beta)}{\sin{(\alpha-\beta)}}\right) & = w \\
 \frac{1}{\sin(\alpha) \cot(\beta) + \cos(\alpha)} + \frac{1}{\sin(\alpha) \cot(\beta) - \cos(\alpha)} & = \frac{w \sin(\alpha)}{h} \\[6pt]
 \frac{2 \cancel{\sin(\alpha)} \cot(\beta)}{\sin^2(\alpha) \cot^2(\beta) - \cos^2(\alpha)}& = \frac{w \cancel{\sin(\alpha)}}{h} \\[5pt]
w \sin^2(\alpha) \cdot \cot^2(\beta) - 2 h \cdot \cot(\beta) - w \cos^2(\alpha) &= 0
\end{align}
$$

The latter is a quadratic in $\,\cot(\beta)\,$. Its determinant $\frac{1}{4} \Delta = h^2 + w^2 \sin^2(\alpha) \cos^2(\alpha) \gt 0$ is positive, so the quadratic has two real roots, and their product is $-\cot^2(\alpha) \lt 0$ so the roots have opposite signs. The positive root corresponds to a $\beta \in (0, \pi / 2)$ which is then the unique solution.

Comment: But you don't know β nor z, so you have 2 unknowns in one equation. Both β and z change in function of w.

Comment: Thanks for the info @dxiv, but I don't see how I can find out the value of β with what you've posted.

Comment: @Enedin My mistake, I misread that $\beta$ was known. Then you can calculate $z'=AB$ the same way as $z$ in terms of $h,\alpha,\beta$ then $z+z'=w$ gives a trig equation to solve for $\beta$. Will update the answer a bit later.

Comment: Damn, that's impressive. I'm going to give this a go right now and see what happens!

Comment: This looks to be correct! Thanks @dxiv, that's mighty impressive :)